# Recursive function not incremeanting its own parameter

Tags: javascript, printjs

```js
var documentURLs = ["maca.pdf", "maca2.pdf"]
function printDocuments(index){
   if(index > documentURLs.length){
        return;
   }
   else {
     printJS({
       printable: documentURLs[index],
       type: 'pdf',
       onPrintDialogClose: function () {
         console.log(index);
          printDocuments(index++)
       }
     })
   }
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="printDocuments(0)">Print</button>
```

This is not incrementing the index, always print first document and it is not stopping

Comment: `index++` means "use the current value of `index`, and then increment it by 1". I think if you change it to `++index` it would work how you'd expect - "increment `index` by one, and then use that value`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It behaves exactly as it should. If you want to call `printDocuments` with the next index, you should use `printDocument(++index)` or just`printDocument(index+1)`, because it's the least confusing one. `i++` returns current value of `i` and then adds 1. `++i` first adds 1 and returns that increased value (so `i+1`).

Comment: Pedantic, but generally `++index` is not quite the same as `index+1`, because the first way also increments its value, while the second only returns the value `index + 1`. Though _in this case_ it's the same because they're not doing anything with `index` afterwards.

Comment: I never said it's the same. It's just in this case incrementing operator, regardless if used as a postfix or prefix introduces unneeded complexity, IMO.

Comment: Yup, just clarifying. I didn't mean to imply you were saying they're the same. :)